# 'Overlay transparent image' jQuery breaks when new class is added

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this script [HERE](http://www.lightningfastmedia.com/How-to-Protect-Your-Work-From-Image-Thieves.html) to overlay a transparent image over photos that I would like to 'protect' on my site. On images that have hyperlinks, I would like be able to give them a special class and make them accessible.

Here is the original script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var pixelSource = 'http://static.squarespace.com/static/51c351f0e4b0c89ff2b61cb8/t/52cc3905e4b0167d33cd524e/1389115653884/Transparent.gif';
var useOnAllImages = true;
// Preload the pixel
var preload = new Image();
preload.src = pixelSource;
$('img').live('mouseenter touchstart', function(e) {
    // Only execute if this is not an overlay or skipped
   var img = $(this);
   if (img.hasClass('protectionOverlay')) return;
   if (!useOnAllImages && !img.hasClass('protectMe')) return;
   // Get the real image's position, add an overlay
   var pos = img.offset();
   var overlay = $('<img class="protectionOverlay" src="' + pixelSource + '" width="' + img.width() + '" height="' + img.height() + '" />').css({position: 'absolute', zIndex: 9999999, left: pos.left, top: pos.top}).appendTo('body').bind('mouseleave', function() {
       setTimeout(function(){ overlay.remove(); }, 0, $(this));
   });
   if ('ontouchstart' in window) $(document).one('touchend', function(){ setTimeout(function(){ overlay.remove(); }, 0, overlay); });
});
});
</script>
```

I was told to change this line:

```
$('img').live('mouseenter touchstart', function(e) {
```

To this:

```
$('img').not('.FreeMe').live('mouseenter touchstart', function(e) {
```

... and  give the images I want to be clickable the class of '.FreeMe'.

When I run the script with no changes, the transparent overlays work great. Once I change that line of code and add the special class, all of the images become accessible again and the script no longer works.

[HERE](http://racermec.com/rmec-gallery) is a link to the page I've been working on. The Photographers information at the bottom of the screen is the image I would like to add a hyperlink to.

I have been searching high and low in order to make this work but was unable to find a solution to the problem. I'm very new to Javascript and jQuery, but know just enough in CSS and HTML to be dangerous.

I appreciate any help you all could provide.

Comment: Beware if you plan to update jQuery: as of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers.

Comment: Thank you, Bigood, for the info!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `.live()`, since the `.live()` method can't be chained like other jQuery methods (the params are just the same).

---

Quoting [jQuery's doc on `.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> Use of the .live() method is no longer recommended since later
>   versions of jQuery offer better methods that do not have its
>   drawbacks. In particular, the following issues arise with the use of
>   .live():
>
> • Chaining methods is not supported. For example, $( "a" ).find(
>   ".offsite, .external" ).live( ... );  is not valid and does not work
>   as expected.

Plus, as said in the comments, as of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated.

You an see a [working demo with adorable kittens here.](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/bQEpB/)

Comment: Thank you helping me to update the jQuery so that it is current with the latest standards... as well as the demo with adorable kittens.

I have updated my code with the updated version you provided, but it still doesn't work correctly if I add the `$('img').not('.FreeMe')` to it.

Comment: After more research and help from a friend, we found that I was missing a set of }); at the end of the script. I could then give the images that I wanted to be excluded from the script the class of .protectionOverlay

Comment: @ESGD Oh right, I didn't notice that when I added your code to JSFiddle… Sorry I missed it! You still have to use `.on()` though.

Comment: Yep, the code has been updated with `.on()`. Thanks again, Bigood!